# Use LispLab within AutoCAD

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-multiplication, autocad, autolisp

Can we use [Lisplab](https://common-lisp.net/project/lisplab/) in LISP within AutoCAD ? If yes, then please help how ?

Answer (score 1):

No. With AutoLISP, you can use COM servers with the `vlax-` functions: http://help.autodesk.com/view/ACD/2017/ENU/?guid=GUID-D5A6811A-F110-49DD-AF83-1F64773D7DC1 or create your own functions with ObjectARX (C++, acedDefun) or [the .NET API](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/search-result/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2015/ENU/AutoCAD-NET/files/GUID-3B2760FE-A0DC-4229-AEBE-5CC83290BA95-htm.html).

You can also look at these links for more information:

- http://alisp-ext.wikidot.com/
- [Visual Lisp: how to call functions in external C++ DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8477753/200443)